# CSipSimple PjSip get some voip metriks

Tags: android, pjsip

I want to display the `VOIP` metrics like packet loss jitter and others.
In the `PJSIP` code there is a class `RTPC.c` where I can get this information. 
So my question is: does `CSipSimple` have a Java-Object that collects this information or can anyone give me an device how to change the Java-Classes to get this information over `JNI`?

Comment: have you found the answer ?